# select from MyBatis only get one result

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, mybatis, spring-mybatis

I am facing a very weird problem.
I used MyBatis generator automatically generate mappers and xml from my MySQL databases.And used the selectByExample method of the mapper to pass criteria trying to verify the user. Below is the code.

```js
@Service
public class EmployeeServiceImpl implements EmployeeService {

 @Autowired
 private EmployeeMapper employeeMapper;
 
 @Autowired
 private EmployeeExample employeeExample;

 
 @Override
 public boolean verify(String username,String password) {
  
  EmployeeExample.Criteria criteria = employeeExample.createCriteria();
  criteria.andUsernameEqualTo(username);
  criteria.andPasswordEqualTo(password);
  List<Employee> list = employeeMapper.selectByExample(employeeExample);
  if(list.size()>0) {
   return true;
  }else {
   return false;
  }
 }

}
```

When I use SpringMVC controller passing the username and password to the mapper, it just returns only one result. When I pass correct information it will return true, but after that, every incorrect information gets true also.

I'm not sure if is it the MyBatis problem or Spring MVC?
Could anyone help me with that?
Really appreciate!

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed the problem with not injecting the EmployeeExample and "new" one instead. But is it violating the decoupling principle? And how that problem happens? Could anyone explain it a little bit? Appreciate again!